# Move DB from Apache to IIS

Tags: 7, migrations, database

I've been working on a Drupal site under a LAMP configuration. My client uses SQL Server, so after I'm done with development I need to move the site over to their configuration. I work on Linux, so I have no way to test the site live (I can remotely connect to my client's server but if I want anything changed I have to go through their IT department, which is painful and slow at best).

I found this module, [driver for SQL Server](https://www.drupal.org/project/sqlsrv), but from the instructions I gather this is for a fresh Drupal install. Could it work, if I already have some work done, to move my current DB over to their server? If not, is there another option to keep working on MySQL and later migrate to SQL 2008?

I'm not familiar with SQL Server, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not a good answer, but I would beg and plead with the customer not to do this thing.

Comment: I already exhausted that option, but as you can see it didn't work. And to add insult to injury, the site must  work on IE7 & IE8 :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would approach your issue:

1. Prepare two IIS+MSSQL servers, [Staging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_site) and Production
2. Do a fresh install on Staging
3. Use tool like [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features), [UUID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid), and data migration module of your choice to move configuration and data from Development to Staging
4. Tie loose ends on Staging
5. Copy Staging to Production
6. Replace my dev with something less unlike production